# How to add multiple javascripts in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme and the javascript files used by that theme is 1.7.2. And I installed a plugin and the plugin using javascript version 3.1.1. If I want to use 3.1.1 then the script used by the theme is not working and if I want to use theme files plugin is not working.

Finally I am searching for a solution how can I use both versions in a single wordpress site

Comment: Welcome to SO. Each plugin/script/theme and WordPress itself have independent versioning systems and the numbers do not have to match. If a particular version of a theme is not compatible with a particular version of a plugin or script, you will have to provide more specific details (as in the names of the said plugins/scripts/theme) so we could provide helpful answers.

Comment: HI thank you for your reply. Theme https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/44910.html  and plugin using was behance.gsamdani.com/gs-behance-portfolio-widget